# Error using set MLFLOW_TRACKING_URI='http://0.0.0.0:5000' for serve models

Tags: python, mlflow

Hi i need to run a command like this

```
mlflow server --backend-store-uri postgresql://mlflow_user:mlflow@localhost:5433/mlflow --default-artifact-root file:D:/artifact_root --host 0.0.0.0 --port 5000
```

for start my serve and i have not problem with this but when i try to run a example
in the route of project from github python

```
mlflow/examples/sklearn_elasticnet_diabetes/linux/train_diabetes.py 0.1 0.9
```

i get this error

```
  _model_registry_store_registry.register_entrypoints()
Elasticnet model (alpha=0.100000, l1_ratio=0.900000):
  RMSE: 71.98302888908191
  MAE: 60.5647520017933
  R2: 0.21655161434654602
<function get_tracking_uri at 0x0000017F3AE885E8>
url 'http://0.0.0.0:8001'
url2 'http|//0.0.0.0|8001'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train_diabetes.py", line 90, in <module>
    mlflow.log_param("alpha", alpha)
  File "C:\Users\kevin.sanchez\Miniconda3\envs\env_mlflow\lib\site-packages\mlflow\tracking\fluent.py", line 210, in log_param
    run_id = _get_or_start_run().info.run_id
  File "C:\Users\kevin.sanchez\Miniconda3\envs\env_mlflow\lib\site-packages\mlflow\tracking\fluent.py", line 508, in _get_or_start_run
    return start_run()
  File "C:\Users\kevin.sanchez\Miniconda3\envs\env_mlflow\lib\site-packages\mlflow\tracking\fluent.py", line 148, in start_run
    active_run_obj = MlflowClient().create_run(
  File "C:\Users\kevin.sanchez\Miniconda3\envs\env_mlflow\lib\site-packages\mlflow\tracking\client.py", line 44, in __init__
    self._tracking_client = TrackingServiceClient(final_tracking_uri)
  File "C:\Users\kevin.sanchez\Miniconda3\envs\env_mlflow\lib\site-packages\mlflow\tracking\_tracking_service\client.py", line 32, in __init__       
    self.store = utils._get_store(self.tracking_uri)
  File "C:\Users\kevin.sanchez\Miniconda3\envs\env_mlflow\lib\site-packages\mlflow\tracking\_tracking_service\utils.py", line 126, in _get_store     
    return _tracking_store_registry.get_store(store_uri, artifact_uri)
  File "C:\Users\kevin.sanchez\Miniconda3\envs\env_mlflow\lib\site-packages\mlflow\tracking\_tracking_service\registry.py", line 37, in get_store    
    return builder(store_uri=store_uri, artifact_uri=artifact_uri)
  File "C:\Users\kevin.sanchez\Miniconda3\envs\env_mlflow\lib\site-packages\mlflow\tracking\_tracking_service\utils.py", line 81, in _get_file_store 
    return FileStore(store_uri, store_uri)
  File "C:\Users\kevin.sanchez\Miniconda3\envs\env_mlflow\lib\site-packages\mlflow\store\tracking\file_store.py", line 100, in __init__
    self.root_directory = local_file_uri_to_path(root_directory or _default_root_dir())
  File "C:\Users\kevin.sanchez\Miniconda3\envs\env_mlflow\lib\site-packages\mlflow\utils\file_utils.py", line 387, in local_file_uri_to_path
    return urllib.request.url2pathname(path)
  File "C:\Users\kevin.sanchez\Miniconda3\envs\env_mlflow\lib\nturl2path.py", line 35, in url2pathname
    raise OSError(error)
OSError: Bad URL: 'http|//0.0.0.0|8001'
```

before running the python code i run this command to set the env tracking uri for the execution set MLFLOW_TRACKING_URI='http://0.0.0.0:5000'

i don´t know why mlflow replace the : for | i need help. Before this option worked but now it is failing

Answer (score 0):

This looks strange because if you set `MLFLOW_TRACKING_URI` to `http://0.0.0.0:5000`, `RestStore` should be used, but your stacktrace says `FileStore` is used. Can you run the code below and see what it prints out?

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
urlparse('http://0.0.0.0:5000')
```

Comment: print this ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='0.0.0.0:5000', path='', params='', query='', fragment='') but the execution still change de : in the url by a |

Answer (score 0):

this error

```
$ python train_diabetes.py 0.1 0.9
C:\Users\kevin.sanchez\Miniconda3\envs\env_mlflow\lib\site-packages\mlflow\tracking\_model_registry\utils.py:106: UserWarning: Failure attempting to register store for scheme "file-plugin": No module named 'mlflow_test_plugin.sqlalchemy_store'
  _model_registry_store_registry.register_entrypoints()
Elasticnet model (alpha=0.100000, l1_ratio=0.900000):
  RMSE: 71.98302888908191
  MAE: 60.5647520017933
  R2: 0.21655161434654602
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train_diabetes.py", line 88, in <module>
    mlflow.log_param("alpha", alpha)
  File "C:\Users\kevin.sanchez\Miniconda3\envs\env_mlflow\lib\site-packages\mlflow\tracking\fluent.py", line 218, in log_param
    run_id = _get_or_start_run().info.run_id
  File "C:\Users\kevin.sanchez\Miniconda3\envs\env_mlflow\lib\site-packages\mlflow\tracking\fluent.py", line 573, in _get_or_start_run
    return start_run()
  File "C:\Users\kevin.sanchez\Miniconda3\envs\env_mlflow\lib\site-packages\mlflow\tracking\fluent.py", line 159, in start_run
    active_run_obj = MlflowClient().create_run(experiment_id=exp_id_for_run, tags=tags)
  File "C:\Users\kevin.sanchez\Miniconda3\envs\env_mlflow\lib\site-packages\mlflow\tracking\client.py", line 54, in __init__
    self._tracking_client = TrackingServiceClient(final_tracking_uri)
  File "C:\Users\kevin.sanchez\Miniconda3\envs\env_mlflow\lib\site-packages\mlflow\tracking\_tracking_service\client.py", line 39, in __init__
    self.store = utils._get_store(self.tracking_uri)
  File "C:\Users\kevin.sanchez\Miniconda3\envs\env_mlflow\lib\site-packages\mlflow\tracking\_tracking_service\utils.py", line 127, in _get_store
    return _tracking_store_registry.get_store(store_uri, artifact_uri)
  File "C:\Users\kevin.sanchez\Miniconda3\envs\env_mlflow\lib\site-packages\mlflow\tracking\_tracking_service\registry.py", line 38, in get_store
    return builder(store_uri=store_uri, artifact_uri=artifact_uri)
  File "C:\Users\kevin.sanchez\Miniconda3\envs\env_mlflow\lib\site-packages\mlflow\tracking\_tracking_service\utils.py", line 81, in _get_file_store
    return FileStore(store_uri, store_uri)
  File "C:\Users\kevin.sanchez\Miniconda3\envs\env_mlflow\lib\site-packages\mlflow\store\tracking\file_store.py", line 132, in __init__
    self.root_directory = local_file_uri_to_path(root_directory or _default_root_dir())
  File "C:\Users\kevin.sanchez\Miniconda3\envs\env_mlflow\lib\site-packages\mlflow\utils\file_utils.py", line 390, in local_file_uri_to_path
    return urllib.request.url2pathname(path)
  File "C:\Users\kevin.sanchez\Miniconda3\envs\env_mlflow\lib\nturl2path.py", line 33, in url2pathname
    raise OSError(error)
OSError: Bad URL: 'http|//0.0.0.0|5000'
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kevin.sanchez\Miniconda3\envs\env_mlflow\lib\site-packages\mlflow\tensorflow.py", line 577, in _flush_queue
    client = mlflow.tracking.MlflowClient()
  File "C:\Users\kevin.sanchez\Miniconda3\envs\env_mlflow\lib\site-packages\mlflow\tracking\client.py", line 54, in __init__
    self._tracking_client = TrackingServiceClient(final_tracking_uri)
  File "C:\Users\kevin.sanchez\Miniconda3\envs\env_mlflow\lib\site-packages\mlflow\tracking\_tracking_service\client.py", line 39, in __init__
    self.store = utils._get_store(self.tracking_uri)
  File "C:\Users\kevin.sanchez\Miniconda3\envs\env_mlflow\lib\site-packages\mlflow\tracking\_tracking_service\utils.py", line 127, in _get_store
    return _tracking_store_registry.get_store(store_uri, artifact_uri)
  File "C:\Users\kevin.sanchez\Miniconda3\envs\env_mlflow\lib\site-packages\mlflow\tracking\_tracking_service\registry.py", line 38, in get_store
    return builder(store_uri=store_uri, artifact_uri=artifact_uri)
  File "C:\Users\kevin.sanchez\Miniconda3\envs\env_mlflow\lib\site-packages\mlflow\tracking\_tracking_service\utils.py", line 81, in _get_file_store
    return FileStore(store_uri, store_uri)
  File "C:\Users\kevin.sanchez\Miniconda3\envs\env_mlflow\lib\site-packages\mlflow\store\tracking\file_store.py", line 132, in __init__
    self.root_directory = local_file_uri_to_path(root_directory or _default_root_dir())
  File "C:\Users\kevin.sanchez\Miniconda3\envs\env_mlflow\lib\site-packages\mlflow\utils\file_utils.py", line 390, in local_file_uri_to_path
    return urllib.request.url2pathname(path)
  File "C:\Users\kevin.sanchez\Miniconda3\envs\env_mlflow\lib\nturl2path.py", line 33, in url2pathname
    raise OSError(error)
OSError: Bad URL: 'http|//0.0.0.0|5000'
```